# Android lost, Gmail password changed. Can Gmail still be viewed?

Tags: gmail, password, lost-phone, cache, offline

I lost my Android phone today so I changed my Gmail account password.

Will whomever that finds it be able to view my offline Gmail (cached) content, even though I changed my account password?

I'm concerned because I'm not usually asked for the password and whenever I'm offline I can see the offline cached content.

Comment: Did you have a screenlock set on your device, such as a pin or pattern? That, at least, would hinder the user from immediate access.

Comment: the pin of the sim if you mean that

Comment: No, the SIM pin only is asked on power-on (or when returning from airplane mode). But didn't the account page @Google have the possibility to revoke access from specified apps/devices? If you had not already changed your password, I had recommended checking the [lost-phone tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info) and push one of the special apps to it. That would have given you the possibility to even remotely wipe the phone. Not sure if that still works with a changed password.

Answer (score 3):

A quick bit of experimentation shows that they will be able to view your cached Gmail, but will not be able to download new mail.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers. unfortunately with the Android Lost application that I tried to install yesterday the phone does not appear to register yet, probably because it is switched off.